# Can I use Entity Framework Core 6 with Windows Forms (use .NET 5)?

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework-core, .net-5, windows-forms-core

Can I use Entity Framework Core 6 with Windows Forms (use .NET 5)?

Is using Entity Framework Core 5 with Windows Forms (use .NET 5) best practice?

Answer (score 1):

EF core 6 is actually targeted for dotnet 6. And dotnet 6 is required for EF core 6.
And yes, if you're working on dotnet 5 app, use EF core 5.